# Ruby: Make a global method that checks my class's type (Pair)

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a global boolean method that checks if a variable is of type `Pair` (my own customized class). However, when I try to run it, I get the error

```
Project4.rb:83:in `<main>': private method `pair?' called for #<Pair:0x00000212de6861e8 @value1=5, @value2=7> (NoMethodError)

puts a.pair?
      ^^^^^^
```

What do I do? My code is below.

```
#Pair (class): Takes two values and creates a list from them. Executing the code should return a list without displaying any output.
#   Returns: A list of at least two elements.
#   Parameters:
#       value1 (any class, including pair) - a value to insert into list.
#       value2 (any class, including pair) - another value to insert into list.
#
#Declare class `Pair`
class Pair
    #Initialize
    def initialize(value1, value2)
        @value1 = value1
        @value2 = value2
    end

    #Method: car - return the car of the pair.
    def car
        return @value1
    end
    
    #Method: cdr - return the cdr of the pair.
    def cdr
        return @value2
    end
    
    #Method: to_s - Return string representation of the pair.
    # def to_s
    #     "(#{@value1} . #{@value2})" 
    # end

    #Method: list? - returns true if pair is a valid list and false otherwise.
    def list?
        #If value2 is a pair...
        if (@value2.class == Pair)
            #...Recursively call the list? method again with the cdr.
            cdr.list? #Recursion
        else
            #If value2 is a null (nil) value, then it is a list.
            if (@value2 == nil)
                return true
            else
                return false
            end
        end
    end

    #Method: count - If the pair is a list, return the number of items in the top level of the list. Return false otherwise.

    #Method: append(other) - If the pair is a list, append should return a new list consisting of `other`` appended to the original list. 

    #Method: null? -  returns true only if the pair is an empty list.
    def null?

    end

    #Implement a null/empty list value.
    def self.null
        nil
    end

end

#Implement a global `pair?` method. MUST NOT TAKE PARAMETERS!
def pair?
    if (is_a? Pair)
        return true
    else
        return false
    end
end
```

Please reply at your earliest conveniene.

Comment: How is the global `pair?` method supposed to work if it doesn't take any arguments? Calling `is_a?` implies that this should be an instance method of `Object`, just like `is_a?` itself.

Comment: BTW, `pair?` is never called in the 60 lines preceding the method definition.

Comment: PSA: Ruby has an implicit `return` which means code that just returns a value can be written without the `return` present. This leads to cleaner more idiomatic Ruby code. You can also remove a "cast boolean to boolean" `if` operation, as in `if (x); true; else; false; end` is effectively equivalent to `x` or, if you need to force boolean, `!!x`.

Comment: Why not name those `@car` and `@cdr` then `attr_reader` both of those?

Comment: Also worth noting here that Ruby's `case` statement makes this kind of code boil down to basically nothing. `case @value2` and `when Pair` vs. `when nil` and `else`.

Comment: The code you showed *cannot possibly* generate the error you showed, and the error you showed refers to code that does not exist in the code you showed. So, clearly, the error is not generated in the code you showed, it must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A global method doesn't require a receiver and can be called in functional form, for example [`puts`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) or [`loop`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Kernel.html#method-i-loop). Your method however does require a receiver because it's based on `is_a?`.

To turn your method into a working global method, you'd need to pass the object:

```
def pair?(obj)
  obj.is_a?(Pair)
end
```

> MUST NOT TAKE PARAMETERS!

Okay, noted. You probably don't want a global method in the first place but an instance method of `Object`:

```
class Object
  def pair?
    is_a?(Pair)
  end
end
```

This is "global" in the sense that you can call it on any object.

You can even omit the explicit type check by utilizing inheritance. Implement a `Object#pair?` method which provides a default value of `false` for all objects:

```
class Object
  def pair?
    false
  end
end
```

and override it in your `Pair` class to return `true`:

```
class Pair
  def pair?
    true
  end
end
```

Example:

```
Object.new.pair? #=> false
"a string".pair? #=> false

Pair.new.pair?   #=> true
```

This is exactly how `nil?` works, see the implementation for [`Object#nil?`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Object.html#method-i-nil-3F) and [`NilClass#nil?`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/NilClass.html#method-i-nil-3F).

Keep in mind that adding methods to `Object` might result in cluttered classes as those methods become available to all objects. It's great for exploring OOP principles but you shouldn't do it in general.

Comment: Good technical answer, but it's worth mentioning that methods like this which inject clutter into `Object` should be avoided unless there's a highly compelling reason to have this convenience method.

Comment: Why does this only work if you name the class `Object`?

Comment: @spaceman777 `class Object` doesn't create a new class. It re-opens the existing [`Object`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.3/Object.html) class which _"[...] is the default root of all Ruby objects."_

Comment: Where could have I found this info? I did not find it in my textbook.

Comment: @spaceman777 which textbook do you have? And what is it you didn't find?`Object` being the root of all object or that you can re-open a class?

Comment: Look at the Ruby docs for [basically any class](https://rubyapi.org/3.3/o/string) and you'll find "Parent" listed as `Object`. This is pretty fundamental to Ruby's "everything is an object" design philosophy.

Comment: This answer is a bit misleading. The OP's code *also* adds an instance method to `Object`, since `Object` is the *default definee* at the top-level. The main difference is that the OP's code creates a `private` method, whereas yours creates a `public` one.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I've deliberately kept the answer simple. You're right, both methods end up in `Object` and the difference is merely their visibility, but the intent is quite different. IMO explaining the inner workings of the top-level is beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Stefan wrote how to define such "global" method to fix the issue with re-opening `Object` class

Let me add some explanation of that issue

When you define method as "global" such way as in your example, you are really define private instance method of `Object` class (one of the top-level classes in the inheritance chain)

```rb
# Define "global" method
def foo
  :bar
end

# Check the owner of this method
method(:foo).owner
# => Object

# Check the method is private
Object.private_instance_methods.grep(/foo/)
# => [:foo]

# Call this method in top-level context (private methods are available)
foo
# => :bar

# Check integer is one of the Object's child
5.class.ancestors
# => [Integer, Numeric, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

# Call this method on some child of the Object (private methods are not available)
5.foo
# `<main>': private method `foo' called for 5:Integer (NoMethodError)

# Hack to call private method
5.send(:foo)
# => :bar
```

Well, may be it is possible to make such "global" method as public without `Object` re-opening

Yes!

```rb
public def foo
  :bar
end

5.foo
# => :bar
```

So additionally to Stefan's way, you can call this method using `send` or define method as public. And BTW all three ways are look not good for me